# I'm getting errors (error 2) while building cross compiler toolchain for ARM

Tags: compiler-construction, embedded, arm, cross-compiling, embedded-linux

I want to **Build a cross compiler toolchain using utilities**.
So i downloaded all `tar` files. then I changed to parent build root directory.

then i configured to ARM & ARM 920T. I unchecked all options which are in `build options --->` and `tool chain--->` (using `make menuconfig`)

```
Target Architecture (arm)  --->                                                                       
Target Architecture Variant (arm920t)  --->   
Target ABI (EABI)  --->
```

**Building Options**

```
  Commands  --->
  ($(TOPDIR)/dl) Download dir
  ($(BASE_DIR)/host) Host dir
  Mirrors and Download locations  --->
  (2) Number of jobs to run simultaneously
[ ] Enable compiler cache
[ ] Show packages that are deprecated or obsolete
[ ] build packages with debugging symbols                                                               
strip (strip)  --->
gcc optimization level (optimize for size)  ---> 
[*] prefer static libraries 
[ ] documentation on the target                                                                          

[ ] development files in target filesystem
```

**TOOL CHAIN**

```
  Toolchain type (Buildroot toolchain)  --->
      *** Kernel Header Options ***
                                 Kernel Headers (Linux 2.6.37.x kernel headers) 
      *** uClibc Options ***
 uClibc C library Version (uClibc 0.9.30.x)  ---> 

               (toolchain/uClibc/uClibc-0.9.30.config) uClibc
configuration file to use? 
[ ] Thread library debugging
[*] Compile and install uClibc tests
*** Binutils Options ***
Binutils Version (binutils 2.21)  --->
()  Additional binutils options
*** GCC Options ***
GCC compiler Version (gcc 4.3.x)  --->
```

I run `make`.

It's giving below error.

```
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot- 2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5-initial/fixincludes'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5-initial/build-i686-pc-linux-gnu/fixincludes'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5-initial/build-i686-pc-linux-gnu/fixincludes'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5-initial/libcpp'
test -f config.h || (rm -f stamp-h1 && /usr/bin/make stamp-h1)
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5-initial/libcpp'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5-initial/gcc'
if [ xinfo = xinfo ]; then \
    makeinfo --split-size=5000000 --no-split -I . -I /home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc \
        -I /home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot- 2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/include -o doc/cpp.info  /home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc- 4.3.5/gcc/doc/cpp.texi; \
       fi
if [ xinfo = xinfo ]; then \
    makeinfo --split-size=5000000 --no-split -I . -I  /home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc \
        -I /home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot- 2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/include -o doc/gcc.info   /home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc- 4.3.5/gcc/doc/gcc.texi; \
fi
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/cppopts.texi:757: @itemx must follow @item
make[2]: *** [doc/cpp.info] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/gcc.texi:89: warning: @tex should only appear at a line beginning
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/gcc.texi:89: warning: @end should only appear at a line beginning
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/gcc.texi:91: warning: @tex should only appear at a line beginning
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/gcc.texi:91: warning: @end should only appear at a line beginning
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/invoke.texi:961: @itemx must follow @item
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/cppopts.texi:757: @itemx must follow @item
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/invoke.texi:8574: @itemx must follow @item
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/extend.texi:4234: @subsection seen before @end table
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/extend.texi:4263: @item outside of table or list
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/extend.texi:4264: @itemx outside of table or list
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/extend.texi:4277: unmatched `@end table'
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/invoke.texi:855: warning: node next `Overall Options' in menu `C Dialect   Options' and in sectioning `Invoking G++' differ
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/invoke.texi:855: warning: node up `Overall Options' in menu `Option Summary' and in sectioning `Invoking GCC' differ
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/invoke.texi:1282: warning: node prev `C Dialect Options' in menu `Overall Options' and in sectioning `Invoking G++' differ
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/invoke.texi:1282: warning: node up `C Dialect Options' in menu `Option Summary' and in sectioning `Invoking GCC' differ
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/invoke.texi:1617: warning: node up `C++ Dialect Options' in menu `Option Summary' and in sectioning `Invoking GCC' differ
/ho me/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/invoke.texi:2198: warning: node up `Objective-C and Objective-C++ Dialect Options' in menu `Option Summary' and in sectioning `Invoking GCC' differ
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/invoke.texi:2475: warning: node up `Language Independent Options' in menu `Option Summary' and in sectioning `Invoking GCC' differ
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/invoke.texi:2536: warning: node up `Warning Options' in menu `Option Summary' and in sectioning `Invoking GCC' differ
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/invoke.texi:4058: warning: node up `Debugging Options' in menu `Option Summary' and in sectioning `Invoking GCC' differ
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/invoke.texi:5102: warning: node up `Optimize Options' in menu `Option Summary' and in sectioning `Invoking GCC' differ
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/invoke.texi:7334: warning: node up `Preprocessor Options' in menu `Option Summary' and in sectioning `Invoking GCC' differ
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/invoke.texi:7371: warning: node up `Assembler Options' in menu `Option Summary' and in sectioning `Invoking GCC' differ
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/invoke.texi:7394: warning: node up `Link Options' in menu `Option Summary' and in sectioning `Invoking GCC' differ
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/invoke.texi:7611: warning: node up `Directory Options' in menu `Option Summary' and in sectioning `Invoking GCC' differ
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/invoke.texi:7749: warning: node up `Spec Files' in menu `Option Summary' and in sectioning `Invoking GCC' differ
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/invoke.texi:8281: warning: node up `Target Options' in menu `Option Summary' and in sectioning `Invoking GCC' differ
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/extend.texi:1122: warning: node next `Zero Length' in menu `Variable Length' and in sectioning `Empty Structures' differ
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/extend.texi:1220: warning: node next `Empty Structures' in menu `Variadic Macros' and in sectioning `Variable Length' differ
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/extend.texi:1220: warning: node prev `Empty Structures' in menu `Variable  Length' and in sectioning `Zero Length' differ
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/extend.texi:1236: warning: node next `Variable Length' in menu `Empty Structures' and in sectioning `Variadic Macros' differ
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/extend.texi:1236: warning: node prev `Variable Length' in menu `Zero Length' and in sectioning `Empty Structures' differ
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/extend.texi:1319: warning: node prev `Variadic Macros' in menu `Empty Structures' and in sectioning `Variable Length' differ
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/extend.texi:1537: warning: node next `Designated Inits' in menu `Cast to Union' and in sectioning `Case Ranges' differ
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/extend.texi:1681: warning: node next `Case Ranges' in menu `Mixed Declarations' and in sectioning `Cast to Union' differ
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/extend.texi:1681: warning: node prev `Case Ranges' in menu `Cast to Union' and in sectioning `Designated Inits' differ
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/extend.texi:1718: warning: node next `Cast to Union' in menu `Case Ranges' and in sectioning `Mixed Declarations' differ
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/extend.texi:1718: warning: node prev `Cast to Union' in menu `Designated Inits' and in sectioning `Case Ranges' differ
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/extend.texi:1759: warning: node prev `Mixed Declarations' in menu `Case Ranges' and in sectioning `Cast to Union' differ
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/extend.texi:3360: warning: node next `Character Escapes' in menu `Variable Attributes' and in sectioning `Alignment' differ
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/extend.texi:3366: warning: node next `Alignment' in menu `Inline' and in sectioning `Variable Attributes' differ
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/extend.texi:3366: warning: node prev `Alignment' in menu `Type Attributes' and in sectioning `Character Escapes' differ
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/extend.texi:3402: warning: node prev `Variable Attributes' in menu `Character  Escapes' and in sectioning `Alignment' differ
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/extend.texi:3938: warning: node next `Type Attributes' in menu `Alignment' and in sectioning `Inline' differ
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/extend.texi:4316: warning: node prev `Inline' in menu `Alignment' and in sectioning `Type Attributes' differ
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/trouble.texi:7: warning: node next `Trouble' in menu `Service' and in sectioning `Bugs' differ
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/trouble.texi:7: warning: node prev `Trouble' in menu `Bug Reporting' and in sectioning `Gcov' differ
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/trouble.texi:7: warning: node up `Trouble' in menu `Bugs' and in sectioning  `Top' differ
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc- 4.3.5/gcc/doc/service.texi:6: warning: node prev `Service' in menu `Trouble' and in  sectioning `Bugs' differ
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/service.texi:6: warning: node up `Service' in menu `Bugs' and in sectioning  `Top' differ
make[2]: *** [doc/gcc.info] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot- 2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5-initial/gcc'
make[1]: *** [all-gcc] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5-initial'
make: *** [/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5-initial/.compiled] Error 2
```

So how can i overcome these errors and build cross tool compiler successfully.

Comment: Seems like you are trying to use Buildroot, but you don't even bother to mention that.  What is your host system?  Have you installed all the required host utilities that Buildroot requires? Buildroot has to be configured for a target board or at least a specific processor.  What is your target board?  **You need to provide more of the console output that preceded the error message:**  *" **???** ... in sectioning `Top' differ"*

Comment: do you need buildroot or just want a gnu toolchain?  you can try github.com/dwelch67/build_gcc as a starting point.  there are many many many other similar scripts to do the same thing.

Comment: Try the option *Remove Documentation* if it exists.  Also, is there a `build.log` somewhere?  The newer **Buildroot** uses [ct-ng](http://crosstool-ng.org/) as the compiler builder.  Put the build.log on pastebin or somewhere and give a link.

Comment: Y cant you use Crosstool-ng ..?

Comment: @sawdust: I have to build cross compiler toolchain. And then build kernel image for ARM. I edited post. Can tell me what's the wrong?

Comment: @SGG - One more time: What is your host system? **Have you installed all the required (mandatory and optional) host utilities that Buildroot requires?**  http://buildroot.uclibc.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#requirement-mandatory  Also try updating the `texinfo` or `texi2html` package.

Comment: @sawdust - My host system is x86 arch, native toolchain compiler: i386. Yes i have installed all mandatory packages.

Comment: *"My host system is x86 arch"*  -- This is like pulling teeth.  What OS/distribution/version?

Comment: @sawdust  i'm sorry. Os: Linux Ubuntu 13.04, kernel ver: 3.11.0-11-generic.

Comment: @sawdust- where i can follow you. bcoz i'm currently learning linux kernel programmimg. I need ur help. plz. Any fb or twitter ID??

Answer (score 6):

You need to read build logs from the top, not the bottom - the fragment you have posted does not provide the full diagnostic.

The *Error 2* you refer to is preceded by an *Error 1* and both are probably merely indications that *make* is terminating due to some *previously* indicated error.  It looks like the following fragment:

```
in sectioning `Top' differ
```

is the end of an *actual* error message that has caused the build to abort.

---

**[Edit 10Oct2013 in response to comment and edited question]**

The actual error that has caused the make to abort is here:

> `/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/cppopts.texi:757: @itemx must follow @item`

i.e. The message immediaty preceeding the *first* make error. As I said - read from the top, not the bottom.

The file is a TeX mark-up documentation file.  I know nothing about TeX, but I imagine that you could edit the file to fix or at least suppress the error.  Alternatively get an updated version of the file, or remove it from the build altogether. Since the documentation of GCC is available on-line, you can probably do without it in any case.

Here is the [TeX documentation for `@itemx`](https://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/texinfo/html_node/_0040itemx.html).  It marks the second and subsequent items in a list started by `@item`.  I imagine that will be easy to fix.

similar issues appear in the following:

```
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/invoke.texi:961: @itemx must follow @item
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/cppopts.texi:757: @itemx must follow @item
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/invoke.texi:8574: @itemx must follow @item
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/extend.texi:4234: @subsection seen before @end table
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/extend.texi:4263: @item outside of table or list
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/extend.texi:4264: @itemx outside of table or list`
/home/gangadhar/Embedded/Embedded/buildroot-2011.02/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/doc/extend.texi:4277: unmatched `@end table
```

You could fix the warnings too perhaps, but the fact that you have these errors suggests that these files have perhaps been modified outside of the GNU GCC project and may no longer be valid or accurate.

Answer (score 6):

Do you still need an answer 9 months after the fact?

Your texinfo is too new.  If you can downgrade to 4.13a, you'll no longer encounter this problem.